# How do redirect cpanel add-on domain away from main domain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cpanel

I'm having an issue setting up an additional domain on Cpanel. My hosting provider does not allow me to move addon domains outside of the main domain's public_html folder. So my add-on domain is publicly available at addon.com, addon.maindomain.com, and maindomain.com/addon.com/

How do I create rewrite rules that will only allow access via the addon.com url?

1. https://addon.com.maindomain.com/ and any optional trailing files/folder structure in the request to https://addon.com
2. https://maindomain.com/addon.com/ and any optional trailing files/folder structure in theh request to https://addon.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon\.com\.maindomain\.com(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/addon\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

This works for part 1 above, but not for any optional trailing files/folder structure. And I'm very unclear how to do part 2. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `\.com(.*)$` makes little sense, you do not expect anything after the `.com`, _in the host name_.

Comment: _"but not for any optional trailing files/folder structure"_ - I can't tell for sure from your phrasing, whether you want to _keep_ the path (and that is not happening), or whether you want to _discard_ it (and that is not happening.) I would assume the former, but please clarify.

Comment: For the second part, `RewriteRule ^addon\.com/(.*) https://maindomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]` should probably do the trick.

Comment: @CBroe - I'm trying to discard it actually.

Comment: `$1` is the back reference to the first grouped match of your rule pattern. So if you don't want that appended - simply remove the `$1` from the end of your substitution URL. (And the _substitution_ is not a regular expression, so you don't need to "escape" dots or slashes in there.)

Comment: And you might want to add the `QSD` flag, otherwise existing query strings will still be added to the new URL.